# Should i separate ContactInfo (sub-entity) from MyTable (main-entity) or Not?

Tags: database-design, normalization

I am designing a database of a school management system. I have one to one relationship of MyTable with ContactInfo table. I am confused whether I separate contactinfo from MyTable or not. ContactInfo record will be single against each MyTable record, but ContactInfo can be updated many times.

Should i merge ContactInfo as
[image: Merged two tables]

or develop a separate ContactInfo as given below 
[image]

Please justified your help with the solid arguments or rule.
Thanks for your help.
Note: ignore the blur fields.

Comment: Why the hell would you separate those ? If all properties belong to the same entity, it goes to 1 table. You could justify 1 to 1 either when you have different entities, or -evntually -  when a field group is rarely used.

Comment: I was just confused with respect to clarity. I think, we should separate a sub-entity separately in a table. To make a database design more understandable and clear.

Comment: @MUHAMMADTASADDUQALI try to be more clear about what you are really asking.

Comment: Ok @jkavalik. I will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know exactly what you mean by 'updated many times' but I presume that you mean that the same `ContactInfo` can be present in multiple `MyTable` entries. In this case I would split it but put the `ContactId` in the `MyTable` entity. This way you are sure that all `ContactInfo` is the same everywhere it is used in `MyTable`.

The rule is that you put all fields that are identified by a single primary key in a separate entity. This way you minimize the number of updates when one of the fields that 'belong' to this primary key changes.

If 1 `ContactInfo` entry has only 1 `MyTable` entry and 1 `MyTable` entry has only 1 `ContactInfo` entry then the separation is not necessary. The only advantages are:

- If the length of an entry is big there is less chance that an entry does not fit in the physical block any more and needs to be 'moved' to an other physical block by the RDBMS.
- When you rarely need to select the `ContactInfo` and `MyTable` at the same time that (with a lot of rows) the fetch in of the rows goes faster since more entries will fit in a physical block.

Comment: thanks, @Marco. I will use ContactId in Mytable. Contactinfo may be added later for a MyTable record.